# syntax for database.table in dbplyr?

Tags: r, dbplyr

I have a connection to our database:

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "myHive")
```

I know this is successful because when I run it, in the top right of RStudio I can see all of our databases and tables.

My question is, how can I select a specific database table combination? The documentation shows a user sleecting a single table, "flights" but I need to do the equivilent of somedatabase.sometable.

Tried:

```
mytable <- tbl(con, "somedb.sometable")
    Error in new_result(connection@ptr, statement) : 
      nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1344: 42S02: [Hortonworks][SQLEngine] (31740) Table or view not found: HIVE..dp_enterprise.uds_order
```

Then tried:

```
mytable <- tbl(con, "somedb::sometable")

Error in new_result(connection@ptr, statement) : 
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1344: 42S02: [Hortonworks][SQLEngine] (31740) Table or view not found: HIVE..somedb::sometable
```

I tried removing the quotes "" too.

Within the connections pane of RStudio I can see somedb.sometable. It's there! How can I save it to variable mytable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You select the database when creating the connection and the table when creating the tbl (with the `from` argument).

There is no standard interface to dbConnect, so the exact way to pass the database name depends on the DBDriver you use. Indeed `DBI::dbConnect` is simply a generic dispatching to the driver-specific `dbConnect`.

In your case, the driver is `odbc` so you can check out [the documentation for `odbc::dbConnect`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/odbc/versions/1.0.1/topics/dbConnect%2COdbcDriver-method) and you'll see the relevant argument is `database`.

This will work:

```r
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "myHive", database = "somedb")
df <- tbl(con, from = "sometable")
```

With most other drivers (e.g. `RMariaDB`, `RMySQL`, `RPostgres`, `RSQLite`), the argument is called `dbname`, so you'd do this:

```r
con <- dbConnect(RMariaDB::MariaDB(), dbname = "somedb")
df <- tbl(con, from = "sometable")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it, use `in_schema`

```
mytable <- tbl(con, in_schema("somedb", "sometable"))
```

This returns  a list not a tbl though so I'm not sure.